# "Invalid combination field1 field2 field3" error message while trying to insert record into postgresql database

Tags: sql, import, insert, postgresql-9.2, database-restore

I'm trying to restore a database from server A to server B.  For some reason, the import fails on 3 specific INSERT statements:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (device_id, group_name, param_id, value) VALUES (15, 'regX', 13, '4323');
INSERT INTO tbl1 (device_id, group_name, param_id, value) VALUES (15, 'device', 1, 'aatd');
INSERT INTO tbl1 (device_id, group_name, param_id, value) VALUES (15, 'regX', 14, 'ttdf');
```

The error returned is:

> **ERROR:  Invalid combination of device, group, and parameter**

It's the same error each record.

**Here's what the table definition looks like:**

```
testdb=# \d+ tbl1; 
                           Table "public.tbl1"
   Column   |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 device_id  | integer                |           | plain    |              | 
 group_name | character varying(255) |           | extended |              | 
 param_id   | integer                |           | plain    |              | 
 value      | character varying(255) |           | extended |              |
```

Other records that look similar work, with no issues. For example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (device_id, group_name, param_id, value) VALUES (103, 'regX', 13, '130');
```

In fact, the database / import file has over 900 records and these are the only 3 that fail.

**How I created the dump file / How I'm importing the dump:**

To export:

```
pg_dump --create -U postgres origdb > outputfile.sql
```

And then on the new server, to import:

```
psql -f outputfile.sql -U postgres
```

**What I've Tried So Far:**

1. I've confirmed that in the original database, these records exist, and match what was generated by the dump command.
   Here's what the data looks like in the original database:

> ```
> origdb=# select * from tbl1 where device_id = 15;
>
>  device_id | group_name | param_id |    value     
> -----------+------------+----------+--------------
>         15 | regX       |       13 | 4323
>         15 | device     |        1 | aatd
>         15 | regX       |       14 | ttdf
> (3 rows)
> ```

1. I've tried to import these records manually on the new server vs. importing the entire dump file.  I get the same error message.
2. I've also been checking to see what pk's have been defined...

> testdb=# SELECT
>         pg_attribute.attname, 
>         format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) 
>       FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute, pg_namespace 
>       WHERE 
>         pg_class.oid = 'tbl1'::regclass AND 
>         indrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
>         nspname = 'public' AND 
>         pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid AND 
>         pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
>         pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey)
>        AND indisprimary;
>
> ```
>  attname | format_type 
> ---------+-------------
> (0 rows)
> ```

**Questions:**

1. I'm not quite sure where it's getting the names "device, group, and parameter" in the error message ... what do these correspond to?  I assume field names, but how can I verify this?
2. Any suggestions on what else to check to troubleshoot? I'm just hunting around to look for any foreign keys on this table etc.?? But any suggestions would be appreciated. 
   I didn't make this database so I'm not sure of all the relations etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a trigger that blocks these specific inserts and displays a custom message.
The trigger can be disabled in the original database but not on the new one.
See your user created triggers with this command:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_trigger;
```

Comment: ah!  interesting.  i do see a few triggers in that table that look suspect.  question:  why do you say I cannot disable the trigger in the new db?  thanks!

Comment: I mean that where disabled in the orginal but now are activated on the new one. You can disable all triggers for table tbl1: 
`ALTER TABLE tbl1 DISABLE TRIGGER USER`